# Laravel Model relationship is not working

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on Laravel project but facing issue with the relationships.

I have CarAddress Model and User Model

in caraddress table, I've id,sessionId,

in users table, I've id and sessioId.

Code in CarAddress model

```
protected $table = 'caraddress';
public $primaryKey ='id';
function users(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','sessionId');
}
```

Code in User model

```
public function CarAddress(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\CarAddress');
    }
```

**Controller code**
    $carAddress =  CarAddress::with('users')->get();
    return $carAddress;

**and result is:**

```
[
{
"id": 25,
"sessionId": "dqEeucFqkNzSUQtPxqdxqvJbCqyrAuVXVqIf3y6l",
"residentialStatus": "homeowner",
"addressYears": "1",
"addressMonths": "0",
"totalMonths": "12",
"postcode": "SW1A 2AA",
"buildingNumber": null,
"street": "10 Downing Street",
"town": "London",
"county": null,
"country": null,
"buildingName": null,
"userRefference": "FFD",
"created_at": "2018-10-20 22:30:44",
"updated_at": "2018-10-19 20:18:22",
"users": null
}
]
```

Comment: and what was supposed to be returned

Comment: user should not null... as there is user data in table

Comment: Is sessionId really equal to users.id?  It doesn't seem like that should be the foreign key here...

Comment: in users table there is also a column name sessionId

Comment: So you need to specify that in the relationship.  You only specified sessionId for one table.  Laravel defaults to id for the foreign, which is usually the right call.

Comment: Yea i tink so according to his question above stating he has a column sessionId related to userId

Comment: I've tried   public function CarAddress(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\CarAddress','sessionId');
        }

Comment: but not worked :(

Comment: do note the belongTo relationship may accept 3 parameters the 1st is the related class and the second is the foreign key of the child table and the 3rd is the column that relates the second parameter in the parent table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to connect the sessionId in both tables, you need to specify both keys:

```
function users(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','sessionId', 'sessionId');
}
```

Some other oddities with your code:

1. It's very unusual to have an id and not use it as the foreign key.  I hope you know what you're doing here.
2. Since this is a belongsTo (**one** to many), the relationship should not be plural.
3. You should follow the naming conventions if this is a new database
   for Laravel.  (session_id)

I highly recommend you read through the entire docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships